# Proxy connection in Jetty with Maven

Tags: maven-2, maven, proxy, maven-jetty-plugin

I am writing a web application with Jetty with Maven. I have a API which tries to connect to web and gets data. I am inside proxy.

I am unable to connect to Net. can i provide somewhere in Maven or Jetty/Maven settings so my web application can get the internet access through proxy ?

each time i am getting Connection timeout.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide more details... For instance, is this java code in your webapp which connects to web?

Comment: Yes, Its a java API written in say Servlet. Its tryign to access net but i am inside Firewall. I can access only through proxy. API dont have any proxy finding.

Answer (score 1):

[This technote](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) illustrates the different ways you can access the internet through proxy from your java code.  It could be as simple as setting the following system properties before running maven

- http.proxyHost: the host name of the proxy server
- http.proxyPort: the port number, the default value being 80.